# Best Method for Importing Very Large CSV into Stata and/or Other Statistical Software

Tags: python, r, import, bigdata, stata

I am trying to import a csv file containing 15 columns totaling 64 GB. I am using Stata MP with a
512 GB RAM computer, which I would presume is sufficient for a task such as this. Yet, I started the import using an import delimited command over 3 days ago, and it still has not loaded into Stata (still shows importing). Has anyone else ran into an issue like this and, if so, is this the type of situation where I just need to wait longer and it will eventually import, or will I end up waiting forever?

Would anyone have recommendations on how to best tackle situations such as this? I've heard that SAS tends to be much more efficient for big data tasks since it doesn't need to read an entire dataset into memory at once, but I do not have any coding knowledge in SAS and am not even sure if I'd have a way to access it. I do have an understanding of Python and R, but I am unsure if either would be of benefit since I believe they also read an entire dataset into memory.

Comment: One option could be to use the `duckdb` library that exists in R or Python to load a larger-than-memory file for analysis. https://duckdb.org/2021/12/03/duck-arrow.html

Comment: You appear to have more than enough memory on your machine. If you used R, you could use the function `fread` from package data.table. I expect it to take a few minutes ([at most](https://github.com/f0nzie/fread-benchmarks-rsuite)) to import a 64 GB CSV.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1677860-importing-very-large-csv-into-stata where there is also commentary